# I keep getting an AttributeError

Tags: python, type-conversion, attributeerror

Here's my code.

```
def square_digits(num):
    str(num)
    num.split()
    for i in num:
        int(i)
        pow(i, 2)
        str(i)
    int("".join(map(str, num)))
    return num
```

Here's the error.

```
    AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `str(num)` does nothing. Strings and integers are both immutable: there are no in-place operations. I suggest reading an introductory Python tutorial.

Comment: Your question example is missing your call of `square_digits(num)` - you could just replace `str(num)` with `num = str(num)` to fix as is; however, you have more pointless casts: `int(i)`, `str(i)` - you need to assign the function result to something.

Comment: @Grismar. Yes. My end is slow to update.

Comment: That's really only part of the error message. Python printed the line that failed too. You need to include that in the question. In this case you should also add the couple of extra lines needed to make this running code. Why make it hard for us?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version of what I think your code is trying to do:

```
def square_digits(num: int) -> int:
    return int("".join(str(int(d)**2) for d in str(num)))
```

Using type annotations like I did above can help you find bugs before running your code.  If I add annotations to your original function:

```
def square_digits(num: int) -> int:
    str(num)
    num.split()
    for i in num:
        int(i)
        pow(i, 2)
        str(i)
    int("".join(map(str, num)))
    return num
```

then when I run `mypy` on it, I get a bunch of errors showing some of what's going wrong:

```
square.py:3: error: "int" has no attribute "split"
square.py:4: error: "int" has no attribute "__iter__"; maybe "__str__", "__int__", or "__invert__"? (not iterable)
square.py:8: error: No overload variant of "map" matches argument types "Type[str]", "int"
```

That first error is the one you're hitting.  `num.split()` doesn't work because `num` is an `int`, and you can't `split` an int.  What you want to `split` is `str(num)`:

```
def square_digits(num: int) -> int:
    for i in str(num).split():
        int(i)
        pow(i, 2)
        str(i)
    int("".join(map(str, num)))
    return num
```

Let's see what errors are left:

```
4: error: No overload variant of "pow" matches argument types "str", "int"
6: error: No overload variant of "map" matches argument types "Type[str]", "int"
```

The first error is because `i` is a `str`, and `pow` wants an `int`.  Let's call it on `int(i)` instead:

```
def square_digits(num: int) -> int:
    for i in str(num).split():
        pow(int(i), 2)
        str(i)
    int("".join(map(str, num)))
    return num
```

Okay, one error left to go, which is that `map` error.  We're trying to map the `str` function over a single `int`, which is our original `num`.  This doesn't make sense; we want to instead map it over a sequence of `int`s, presumably the same ones that we computed during our loop just a second ago.  Let's create a list called `digits` that we can put those ints into:

```
from typing import List


def square_digits(num: int) -> int:
    digits: List[int] = []
    for i in str(num).split():
        digits.append(pow(int(i), 2))
    int("".join(map(str, digits)))
    return num
```

Now there are no more `mypy` errors, but whenever we call our function it just returns the same number that we passed in!  No surprise there; the last line of the function is `return num`, which is the original value.  Let's just change that so we're returning the new value that we've gone to all this effort to compute:

```
from typing import List


def square_digits(num: int) -> int:
    digits: List[int] = []
    for i in str(num).split():
        digits.append(pow(int(i), 2))
    return int("".join(map(str, digits)))
```

This is roughly the same as the version I gave at the top of this answer; I just used a more concise generator expression to do the loop and join it back together all in one shot.  :)